# Script identification Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this script and it helps me to click within a script that is inside an iframe and when I click this iframe the script inside the iframe executes, and closes the iframe.

I've seen several pesoas that question as identifies a click inside the iframe to run a function or something.
I believe that this script can help do this.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$.enableFrameClick = function(){
    var decoy = $('<a href="#"/>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        right:0,
        top:0,
        width:1,
        opacity:0
    }).click(function(e){ return false }).appendTo(document.body);


$(window).blur(function(){
    if ($.inFrame){
        $('#'+$.inFrame).trigger('vclick');
        setTimeout(function(){
            decoy.focus();
        }, 10);
    }
});

var ids = +(new Date);
$('iframe').each(function(){
    if (!this.id){
        this.id = ++ids;
    }
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $.inFrame = this.id;
    }, function(){
        $.inFrame = null;
    })
});
};

$('iframe').bind('vclick', function(){
    $.ifrm(1);
    //log(['[',++i,']','clicked', this.id].join(' '));
});

function log(m){
    //$('#log').text(m);
    //console.log(m);
}

var i = 0;

$.ifrm = function(r){
    $.get("http://chefreceitas.com.br/"+r, function(html,status){
        $('iframe').attr("src",html);
        if(r == 1)
            html = '';
        if(html == '')
            $('iframe').remove();
    });
};

$.enableFrameClick();
$.ifrm(0);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking...

Comment: @Ted Explain in detail what is done in this script. I posted.

Comment: I really cannot understand what the question/problem is. Can you you elaborate?

Comment: Are you asking _us_ to explain what _your_ code does?